# Cooking apples and cleaning ladies

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, gerunds, parts-of-speech, ing

Consider the following sentences:

1. *Cooking* is my favourite activity.
2. *Cooking apples* are essential for this recipe.

*Cooking* functions in the first sentence as a gerund. How does it function in the second?

A similar question could be asked of the term *cleaning lady*. However, while a *cooking apple* represents an apple which is (**itself**) *cooked*, a *cleaning lady* represents a lady who *cleans* (**something else**). Is there a difference?

Other examples:

- *Talking point* vs. *Watering can*
- *Reading material* vs. *Cutting board*

Comment: A "cooking apple" isn't necessarily an apple that has already been cooked, but rather one that is suitable for cooking. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooking_apple)

Comment: In the second example it's also a gerund, but used as an attributive nominal. In "cleaning lady" the form could be parsed as either a gerund (lady who does the cleaning) or as a participle used as an adjective (the lady who is cleaning).

Comment: @simchona Yes, but it's an apple which is cooked, rather than an apple which does the cooking.

Comment: Substitute *Running*, *Running shoes* and either *Running lady* or *Running crew*.

Comment: It's an apple *for cooking*, distinguishing it from one that is *cookable* or one that is *cooked*.

Comment: @coleopterist: an attributive noun/gerund is not about who the actor is. What kind of apple/lady? Something to do with cooking/cleaning.

Comment: @TimLymington I see. Maybe I'm over-thinking this. Would the same apply with, say, _talking point_? A point for talking?

Comment: @Mitch Thanks. To me, it appears to be a subtle distinction. A _talking point_ is a _point which is talked about_ while a _watering can_ is a _can which waters_ rather than a _can which is watered_.

Comment: But a *watering can* does not, itself, "water"; it's a can you use  *for watering*. *Watering eyes*, on the other hand, are eyes which are watering.

Comment: @StoneyB Let me put it another way. A talking point is a point which is talked about. But a watering can is not a can which is watered. Both these terms have the same structure. But they do not do so when expanded using this template. They do, as all the comments have explained, fit the "for" template where they become "a point for talking" and "a can for watering" respectively. IMO, this is a distinction. Moreover, the "for" template appears to neutralise the attribution. \*sigh\* I can tell that I'm not explaining this well.

Comment: No, I understand you perfectly. The problem is the language, which is designed to confuse when you try to think about it instead of just using it! ... Lemme take a stab at an answer.

Comment: SUre, but all I'm saying is that 'an X-ing Y' the 'X-ing' doesn't have the fixed transformation about X beyond 'something about X'. It's not always 'a Y that does X' or 'an X kind of Y' or 'a Y done by X'. It's just 'an X having to do with X-ing'. That's all and context or implicature or culture narrows it down to who the agent is, if any.

Comment: I think the simple answer is, Yes, that's right. "An Xing Y" just means "a Y that has something to do with the action of X". It could mean that Y does X ("cleaning lady"), that Y can be done to X ("roasting pig"), that Y is a tool for doing X ("running shoes"), maybe other variations. It's only non-ambiguous because we know by convention what it means in each case. I'm sure you could come up with examples where someone who was not familiar with a particular term might be confused. But then, in general someone who doesn't know the definition of a word could be confused by it.

Comment: Is it just me, or does "an X-ing Y" sound like a euphemism for an obscene remark?

Comment: What @Mitch said - 'an X-ing Y' just uses *X-ing* as a general-purpose adjective, where the precise relationship of X to Y depends on context. No different to the adjective *red*, which often/normally means *"made of material which [absorbs green light](http://firstyear.chem.usyd.edu.au/calculators/colour_wheel.shtml)"*. But not if it's a ***red alert***, for example.

Comment: @Jay (2 back): If I might drop the articles: flying planes can still be dangerous. Flying boats could possibly be problematic. -ing forms, often somewhere along the noun - verb continuum (see Quirk), but also appearing as adjectives (and secondary modifiers), often give rise to ambiguities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following sentences (stressed words are boldfaced):

1. *Cooking **apples** is essential for this recipe.*
2. ***Cooking*** apples are essential for this recipe.

In (1), *cooking apples* is an example of a [gerund](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) subject [complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf) with a (deleted) indefinite subject. As usual in a transitive subjectless clause, the direct object gets stressed. And, of course, noun clauses are always singular, whence the predicate ***is*** essential.

In (2), however, *cooking apples* is an example of a noun phrase with an attributive adjective formed from a participle, modifying *apples*, and signifying apples intended to be cooked (as opposed -- in my idiolect, anyway -- to *eating apples*, which are intended to be eaten uncooked). As usual in a contrastive noun phrase, the contrasting adjective is stressed. And of course the plural noun *apples* takes a plural predicate ***are*** essential.

- One main point is that not every *-ing* word is a gerund.
- Another is that gerunds are really clauses, with subjects (often deleted,
  but still understood), and possibly objects, if the gerund is transitive.
- Still another is that, when pronounced, there is no ambiguity, because they're not the same.

**Edit:** (added from the comments)

Cooking apples are for cooking, cleaning ladies are for cleaning. The fact that *apples* is object and *ladies* is subject gets lost when the compound is made. There are many many different kinds of noun compound; my favorite pair is *pony ride* vs *snake bite*.

Comment: And 'Cleaning ladies __is__ essential for ...', well, can't they do it themselves?

Comment: Thanks John. Could you please also explain the distinction between "cooking apples" and "cleaning ladies"? The apples are cooked. But the ladies are not cleaned.

Comment: @coleopterist - No, The apples are not cooked. They are apples of the kind that are used to cook with (as opposed to eating apples, or cider apples). Different varieties of apples are meant for different purposes, and these are meant for cooking with. Typically a cooking apple would be smaller and perhaps tarter than an eating apple. They are trying to make sure you don't go out and buy one of those big red eating apples. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooking_apple

Comment: @T.E.D. This is talked about in the comments attached to the question. If you like, you can leave apples out of it altogether and consider the phrases _talking point_ or _reading material_ instead.

Comment: Cooking apples are for cooking, cleaning ladies are for cleaning. The fact that _apples_ is object and _ladies_ is subject gets lost when the compound is made. There are many many different kinds of noun compound; my favorite pair is _pony ride_ vs _snake bite_.

Comment: I see. I see. I guess that these would then be verb-noun compounds. The [WP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Types_of_compound_nouns) contrasts _playboy_ with _callgirl_ which is a distinction similar to the one alluded to in my question. P.S. I've put together an [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/87370/23608) using material I came across while looking up "gerund subject complement". Please comment.

Comment: I find most interesting your parsing of *cooking* here as a  participle rather than a gerund. A)Does it matter? (That's a serious question) B)If so, why a participle rather than a gerund or, perhaps, some tertium quid?

Comment: _Participle_ refers to the **form** of the verb; the _-ing_ form of a verb is technically called the Present Active Participle, just as the _-ed/-en_ form is called the Perfect Passive Participle. Neither name says anything about usages of the form in constructions.

Comment: Alas, modern nomenclature trips me once more: I was taught to use "**-ing** form" for the form and to distinguish participial uses from gerundial.

Comment: What about deverbal, such as _etchings_? Quirk and Greenbaum postulate a 15-element gradience in the verb (present participle -- eg he was painting) -- in-between forms (including what was traditionally labelled gerund -- eg he likes painting) -- deverbal noun (eg he dropped the painting on my foot) continuum. A fudge with -ing forms used adjectivally is: call them participial adjectives (alongside the similar adjectivals - such as hardened criminals, spent force, broken heart - using so-called -ed forms). But grammarians can't even agree on whether participial adjectives are true adjectives!

Comment: Q&G go into more detail than is relevant here, but there is evidence for at least 5 different usages in English. I've listed them, but not tried to grade them on nouniness, [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html).

Comment: Thank you. May I quote the reference on another website?

Comment: It's public, so quote it anywhere you like; that's what it's for.

Answer (score 6):

A *gerund* in English is an **-ing** form of a verb used as a noun. Compare

> *Cooking* is my favorite activity.  ... *Running* is my favorite activity. —  The noun is the subject.
>   *Cooking* apples are essential. ... *Running* shoes are essential.  —The noun is an attributive.

One difficulty here is that gerunds used attributively may have different semantic relationships to the root verb.

1. *Running* shoes, *watering* cans, *grappling* hooks are tools designed for use in the activity — like *soccer* balls.
2. *Cleaning* ladies, *running* crews, *teaching* assistants are people who perform the activities — like *soccer* teams.
3. *Cooking* apples, *reading* material, *riding* horses are the objects operated upon by the activity — like *soccer* coaches.

Another difficulty is that the **-ing** form also serves as the *participle* and maybe used as an adjective. In this use it overlaps with the second use of the gerund, and really the only way to distinguish them in any given context is to ask whether the implication is that the modified 'actor' performs the act just once ir performs it habitually:

> The running lady bumped into an elderly gentleman.
>   The running crew are called for 6 pm.

Sometimes, however, both are true:

> The cleaning lady picked up her broom.

In this case, a distinctive test is to ask whether you can flip the actor and the modifier and keep the meaning

> ?The lady cleaning the room picked up her broom? ‐ probably not; that's a different kind of 'lady'.
>   ?The lady running down the street bumped into an elderly gentleman? — probably; that's the same kind of lady.

Comment: 'One difficulty here is that gerunds used attributively may have different semantic relationships to the root verb.' _Cooking apples_ are usually cooked before they are eaten (often in a pie, say). They contrast with _eating apples_, which are usually eaten uncooked. Logically, both are 'eating' apples, but _eating apples_ might be better termed _non-cooking apples_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Well, if you're going to bring logic into it we're all out of a job :)

Comment: The more common expression is "apples for eating out-of-hand."

Comment: @Merk: Not where I live.

Comment: Thanks. The categories are handy to visualise the different types. (I'm not sure if _soccer coaches_ works as an example.) I've also regurgitated an answer of my own using something I found on the net. Please have a look.

Answer (score 5):

It’s helpful to distinguish form and function in these cases. Perhaps in an attempt to do so, grammarians, in describing the former, seem increasingly to refer to ‘the *–ing* form of the verb’, rather than using terms like gerund or verbal noun. No one can dispute that that is what it is, and it leaves the way clear for an examination of the function.

This form of the verb can perform verbal, nominal and adjectival functions. In your first example, cooking is, as you say, a noun, functioning as the subject of *is*. In the second, it’s an adjective, modifying *apples*.

If we speak or hear of *a cleaning lady*, we know that *cleaning* is an adjective because, if for no other reason, *cleaning* and *lady* quite often collocate in this way. It is hard to think of circumstances in which we would want to use *a cleaning lady* to describe a woman who was actually engaged in household cleansing duties at the time of speaking. In other words, a *cleaning lady* is a lady who cleans, and not a lady who is cleaning.

In your other examples, the *-ing* forms are also adjectives. They are, however, a little different, in that we can’t say that they describe *an X that does something* rather than *an X that is doing something*. They do neither. A *talking point* doesn’t talk, *reading material* don’t read, a *cutting board* doesn’t cut and a *watering can* doesn’t . . .  Ah. Well, yes, a watering can does water, but the point is that it doesn’t water of its own accord. It’s a can **for** watering, just as a cutting board is a board **for** cutting.

In these cases, ambiguity is unlikely. The ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ points out that ambiguity with the use of ‘-ing’ form can nevertheless arise when it follows a main verb (Is it a noun or a verb?), when it modifies a following noun (Is it a noun or an adjective?) and where it follows the verb *be* without other modifiers (Is it a verb or an adjective?).

Answer (score 2):

[A glossary](http://homepages.uwp.edu/canary/grammar_text/glossary_of_terms.html) maintained by an [English professor](http://homepages.uwp.edu/canary) includes the following definitions:

> **Gerund**, **Gerund Phrase**
>
> A present participle used in a nominal position. *A gerund with its complement and/or specifying subject* is called a **gerund phrase.** The "subject" of a gerund phrase is usually in the possessive (genitive) case, serving in effect as the determiner of the phrase, but one does find the objective (accusative) case on occasion, and that seems especially natural when the gerund phrase is serving as a direct object. Direct object gerund or gerund phrases cannot be made passives.

That would perhaps make a *gerund phrase* synonymous with the "gerund subject complement with a (deleted) indefinite subject" in [John Lawler's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/87300/23608).

More interesting is the entry for [*gerundive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundive) where one of the examples—and an excellent one at that—used is **chewing gum**:

> **Gerundive**
>
> Another term from Latin grammar, gerundive, is *sometimes* applied to some or all present participles as premodifiers, but most authorities avoid the term, since English participial premodifiers are not really equivalent to the traditional gerundive found in Latin and some other languages, which implies that something should or must undergo the action specified. Some Latin gerundives of this sort have become independent words in English, like agenda, but English generally uses passive infinitive phrases for this meaning –agenda, for example, would be translated as "to be done." English present participle modifiers usually have the noun modified as the subject of underlying sentences–e.g., overflowing cup implies the cup is overflowing–leaving underlying passive to be expressed with past participle premodifiers–e.g., the frightened cows implies the cows are frightened or Something has frightened the cows. *There are, however, a handful of present participle premodifiers which are equivalent to passive infinitives–e.g., **chewing gum is gum to be chewed** as opposed to chewed gum which is gum that has been chewed. Using **gerundive** for such cases may not be entirely inappropriate.*

Then, by definition, *cooking* in *cooking apples* (apples *to be* cooked) is also a gerundive. This would presumably not apply to *cleaning* in *cleaning lady*.

Comment: This doesn't explain what a _cleaning lady_ is a form of ...

Comment: +1 This is valuable. I toyed with the idea of introducing "gerundive" into the conversation, but dropped it because A)it doesn't really sort with the Latin usage, which says of specific apples that they **should** be cooked **now** rather than (as in the English construction) that they are of the sort which may be cooked  B)I have an ideological objection to importing even more Latin terms into our discourse on English grammar instead of inventing our own terms which describe what we actually do.

Comment: Adding unnecessary names for grammatical constructions is a lot of fun, unless the purpose is to clarify instead of obfuscate. We have way too many terms used inaccurately already; why add more.

Comment: @John Lawler - There you really have a point. +1

Answer (score 2):

As the ing-form can be participle and gerund and as both can stand before a noun as in running shoes you have to decide by logic whether it is a participle as in "a weeping girl" or a gerund.

The transformations of gerunds as in running shoes are "shoes for running" or "shoes used for running", cooking apples are apples used for cooking,   a cleaning lady is the lady who does the cleaning. In this latter case cleaning might be a participle but cleaning lady is a common expression for a professional activity and from the context it should be clear what is meant as in

- The cleaning lady comes on Friday.