# Is this a predicative adjunct?

Tags: complements, adjuncts

> At breakfast on Thursday **she bored them all stupid** with flying tips she'd gotten out of a library book called Quidditch Through the Ages.
>
> –– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

As far as I understand from CGEL (p.251, 262~3), it seems like *stupid* is *a predicative adjunct* whose predicand is *them all*; while in *Kim seemed uneasy*, *uneasy* is the predicative complement. And *stupid* modifies the predicator, *bored*. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: I'd say yes. *She* is the subject and is necessary. *bore* is the verb and part of the predicate and is necessary. It's transitive and requires an direct object: *them all*. So, all you need is: "She bored them all". *Stupid* is part of the predicate "to bore (so) stupid" but doesn't add any value.

Comment: I would argue that "all" is only in there for emphasis and the the essential parts are "she bored them stupid", i.e "she bored them to a state of stupidity".

Comment: _Bore/Talk `X` silly/stupid/to death_ is a causative construction (which other words also participate in) meaning 'talk/bore `X`, with the result that `X` become silly/stupid/dead'. There are a lot of other types of these constructions, which is why I don't like the phrase "predicative adjunct" -- it's a wastebasket category that doesn't identify either form or function. _Shoot `X` dead_ is causative, but not _bury `X` alive_ or _capture `X` alive_. This is [the Green Conspiracy](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/87300/15299) again.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I understand that CGEL would say ['she shot him dead'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111062/can-object-complements-make-any-difference-to-sentences/111065#111065) has resultative adjunct (p.251); 'They buried him alive' depictive one. For the former "denote a change of state." It seems like Green and CGEL have very similar ideas.

Comment: Although I don't like naming grammatical constructions according to what they're sposta mean; meaning is not observable, whereas patterns of usage are.

Comment: Looks like a "resultative [secondary predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate)": *John pounded the metal **flat**.*

Comment: "He painted the door green" is  simple sentence strucure children handle without out difficulty. You use three terms outside traditional grammar - adjunct, predicand, predicator. If a grammar needs 1000 terms for describing language something must be really wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Em1 notes in the comments:

> *She* is the subject and is necessary. *bore* is the verb and part of the predicate and is necessary. It's transitive and requires an direct object: *them all*. So, all you need is: "She bored them all". *Stupid* is part of the predicate "to bore (so) stupid" but doesn't add any value.

Using the [classifications noted on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)#Semantic_function), "stupid" seems to fit best with "measure":

> Measure - Measure adjuncts establish the measure of the action, state, or quality that they modify
>
> - I am completely finished.
> - That is mostly true.
> - We want to stay in part.

"Stupid" is, more or less, a degree of boredom and isn't a literal state of being stupid. Or, in other words, she didn't cause them to *become* stupid; she simply bored them greatly.

Answer (score 2):

> At breakfast on Thursday she bored them all **stupid** with flying tips she'd gotten out of a library book called Quidditch Through the Ages.

I guess that one possible name for **stupid** is a "resultative [secondary predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate)". A resultative secondary predicate describes what state the verb's argument has assumed as a result of the event expressed by the verb:

> Stan cooked the steak **black**
>   Boris pounded the metal **flat**

She bored them to a dazed, "stupid" condition.

---

In the parlance used by Huddleston and Pullum, **stupid** is not an adjunct either. They write:

> Obligatory predicatives are clearly complements, dependent on the occurrence of an appropriate verb. With optional ones, however, there are grounds for saying that while the resultatives are complements, the depictives are adjuncts. (Chapter 4, §5.3, "*Optioinal depictive predicatives as adjuncts*")

In your example sentence, **stupid** describes the result. It is not depictive. In H&P's terminology, it is an "optional resultative predicative complement". It's object-oriented: its predicand is "them (all)".

Answer (score 2):

" she bored them all stupid"

"stupid" modifies the object "them" so I would call it an object complement or if you want "a predicative complement modifying the object". Much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the correct interpretation.  "Stupid" is an adjunct, since the example sentence without it is acceptable and has a meaning which is a part of the meaning of the sentence with "stupid".  "Stupid" is predicated of "them all", so it is predicative.  Since it is an adjunct and is predicative, it is a predicative adjunct.